# Gradle `project` variable in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio versions prior to 3.5 I was able to check if the code was being compiled due to a rebuild or just due to a `Instant Run` invocation, which allowed me to upload the generated APK to a server only if a rebuild was made, by checking

```
def do_upload = true
if (project.property('android.optional.compilation').toString().contains("INSTANT_DEV")) {
  do_upload = false
}
```

This is no longer working<strike>, because `project` is no longer a hashmap (or whatever type of dictionary it used to be), but now it appears to be a string or something containing `project ':app'`</strike>

Where can I now find this `android.optional.compilation` information?

Comment: `./gradlew app:properties` lists them.